# Plotting multiple lines of code with high resolution

Tags: r, plot, graphics, resolution

I have made a bar-plot in R, using several commands. Now I want to save the plot with high resolution. To do that, I am using the tiff() function. However, then only the first command is saved in the tiff. Is there:
a) A way to write several lines of code to one file? or
b) A way to include the 2nd to last command in to the first command, so that everything gets written to the tiff?

The code I've used is (with example numbers):

```
Means <- array(NA, dim=c(2,5))
Means[1,] <- c(9, 7, 4, 2, 3)
Means[2,] <- c(8,4,3,1,5)
SE <- array(NA, dim=c(2,5))
SE[1,] <- c(0.5, 0.4, 0.6, 0.3, 0.2)
SE[2,] <- c(0.4, 0.5, 0.3, 0.1, 0.25)

Top <- max(Means) + max(SE)
tiff("Example.tiff", width = 4, height = 4, units = 'in', res = 300)

BarCenters <- barplot(height = Means,
                   beside = TRUE, las = 1,
                   ylim = c(0, 12),
                   cex.names = 1,
                   col=c("gray35","gray85"),
                   main = "",
                   ylab = "",
                   cex.lab=1.1,
                   border = "black", axes = TRUE,
                   legend.text = TRUE,
                   args.legend = list(x = "topright", cex = .85))
title(ylab="Example", line=2.5, cex.lab=1.2)

segments(BarCenters, Means, BarCenters, Means + SE, lwd = 1.5)

arrows(BarCenters, Means, BarCenters, Means + SE, lwd = 1.5, angle = 90,     
code = 3, length = 0.05)

text(BarCenters, Means + SE, labels = Means, pos = 3, cex = .75)
```

Comment: Have you tried to add `dev.off()` after the last line?

Comment: That solved it! Thanks a lot.